# relational database

Tags: relational-database

how can i insert values in three tables using asingle insert query using single button

Comment: Please consider a more specific title for your question than "relational database".

Comment: You need to learn how to ask questions here. http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please read an intro to SQL & show us some code. Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Some databases allow you to post values into a view, and your view can come from many tables. A perhaps easier way is to perform the three INSERTs in a transaction.